# Code block treats characters not being escaped

Tags: block-editor, code, htmlspecialchars-decode

I want to add some 'c' and 'assembly' code in my post but the characters end up not being escaped, see the pictures below please:

A C code that I put into the editor:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Results after publishing/preview in:

[image]

And here a bit assembly:

```
main:
        push    {r4, lr}
        ldr     r3, .L4
        ldr     r2, .L4+4
        ldr     r1, [r3]
        ldr     r2, [r2]
        ldr     r0, .L4+8
        bl      printf
        mov     r0, #0
        pop     {r4, lr}
        bx      lr
```

results in:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you adding the code to the post? A block, shortcode, raw HTML?

Comment: I'm not seeing any code to debug in your question, can you edit the question to include it?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I just copy it from my IDE and then paste it in wordpress editor

Comment: @TomJNowell I added the code as text (was img before)

Comment: @TomJNowell In the editor they look OK, only after publishing or preview they look wiered!

Comment: @DEKKER I meant the code that implements the block, rather than the code content you're trying to insert and display, it's not clear which block you're using, e.g. are you asking about the code block that comes with WordPress core? Did you build the block yourself? Is it a 3rd party syntax highlighting block? The standard code block that comes with WordPress doesn't normally have line numbers and highlighting

Comment: @DEKKER, are you using a syntax highlighter plugin or did you use your browser's "View Source" feature or maybe your HTML editor software, and took a screenshot of that? And I'm confused - the screenshots showed that special characters (e.g. HTML tags) were (correctly) escaped, but then you said "the characters end up not being escaped" - are you concerned that the characters were **not** escaped, or that they were escaped (e.g. `<` becomes `&lt;`, and `[` becomes `&#91;`)? What did you *see on screen* and what should instead be shown, or the output you were expecting?

Comment: @TomJNowell  sorry, I misunderstood. It appears that I am using Crayon Syntax Highlighter

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes I just found out I am using "Crayon Syntax Highlighter" plugin

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering you all, I found out there is an option in the syntax highlighter plugin that I am using "Crayon Syntax Highlighter" and by checking the "decode HTML entities in code" in the plugin it now shows correctly